# Finding Sufficient Statistic of an Interesting Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

**Question**

A random variable $X$ has the following pdf

$$\frac{\delta}{2}|x|^{\delta-1} \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}(x)$$

where $\delta$ is a positive constant, and $\mathbf{1}$ is the indicator function. What is the sufficient statistic for $\delta$?

**Approach Tried and Problems**

I recognise that the associated iid random sample has the following likelihood function:
$$L\left(\delta | x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\delta}{2}\left|x_{i}\right|^{\delta-1} \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}\left(x_{i}\right)=\left(\frac{\delta}{2}\right)^{n} \prod_{i=1}^{n}\left|x_{i}\right|^{\delta-1} \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}\left(x_{i}\right) $$

But how should I recognise the sufficient statistic using Factorisation Theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likelihood depends only on

$\prod\limits_{i = 1}^n {{{\left| {{x_i}} \right|}^{\delta  - 1}}}  = {\left| {\prod\limits_{i = 1}^n {{x_i}} } \right|^{\delta  - 1}}$

Therefore, by Fisher factorization lemma

$T\left( {{x_1},...,{x_n}} \right) = \prod\limits_{i = 1}^n {{x_i}} $

is a sufficient statistic for $\delta $.